# How can I add new rules to loaders while using VUE CLI 3.x

Tags: html, vue.js, webpack

In the last couple of days I have tried to refer a HTML page inside Vue-router, but no matter what I have tried, the only thing I got back is the following error:

> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.

I have already attempt many different stack responses to fix it, but most of them actually requires to add an extra rule inside `webpack.config.js`.

```js
{
  test: /\.(html)$/,
  use: {
    loader: "html-loader",
    options: {
      attrs: [":data-src"]
}
```

However in the latest version of Vue CLI, it looks like this file is not available anymore.

The HTML page is placed in the `public/static` directory, so it is running fine when I access it from  `localhost:8080/static/home.html`, but my goal is to access it as my home page (using `localhost:8080/`  only) .

So far I have already installed both `html-loader` and `vue-loader` and yet no sign of success.

P.S. I have tried to convert this HTML file and its complementary files (css, fonts and js) into a component, but I had no success as well.

Comment: can you try `test: /\.html$/` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vue CLI [uses `webpack-chain` internally](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#chaining-advanced) for maintaining the Webpack config, and so to configure it you need to add a [`vue.config.js`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js) file to your project (in place of this `webpack.config.js`).

And to configure the loaders you will need the following (inside the `vue.config.js`), of course with the `html-loader` package also installed:

```js
module.exports = {

  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('html')
      .test(/\.html$/)
      .use('html-loader')
      .loader('html-loader')
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi, html-loader works by default without any config. But adding your snippet results in an error, 'These relative modules were not found:' (and shows some contents from html, eg. .css file). I'm trying to turn off minimize for production by adding ```.tap(options => {
                // modify the options...
                return { minimize: false }
            })```

Comment: To change options: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#modifying-options-of-a-plugin