# VueJs How do i load html from api calls or html files?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Good day.
I am trying to create a page where i can show a few different charts that come from either API calls, using axios, or from html files saved in my project directory.

How do i show these charts in my VueJS page?

I've tried the following:

```
<template>
<v-main>
    <v-container>
        <v-row align='center' justify="center">
            <v-col
            class="d-flex justify-center"
            cols="6"
            >
                <v-card
                class="mx-auto"
                width="100%"
                min-height="200px"
                outlined
                >
                <span v-html="HTMLcontent"></span>
                </v-card>
            </v-col>
        </v-row>                 
    </v-container>
</v-main>
</template>

<script>
import html from "@/components/graphs/myCharts.html"

export default {
    computed:{
    },
  data: () => ({
      HTMLcontent: null
  }),
  methods: {
  },
  created() {
    this.HTMLcontent = html
  },
};
</script>
<style scoped>
</style>
```

I also tried using [html loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-loader) but nothing is shown or i either get errors being shown

Here's my webpack configuration ins my vue.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {


"transpileDependencies": [
    "vuetify"
  ],
  configureWebpack: {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.html$/i,
          loader: 'html-loader',
        },
      ],
    },
  }
  
}
```

Comment: What are the errors you saw?

Comment: errors such as: 'You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file' and 'Mixed spaces and tabs  no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs'

Comment: could you also share your webpack configuration?

Comment: the webpack configuration has been added

Comment: I'm not sure about what the problem is but this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59960121/how-can-i-add-new-rules-to-loaders-while-using-vue-cli-3-x